# Asymptotic expansion at $x=1^-$ for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^{a_n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, tauberian-theory

I feel that this general fact should be known. Suppose I have a strictly increasing sequence of integer positive numbers $\{a_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$. We want to investigate the behavior of
$$ f(x)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^{a_n}.$$
Of course this is a power series with convergence radius $R=1$. I want to know something about the limit $\lim_{x \to 1^-} (1-x)^{\alpha} f(x)$, depending on $\alpha$. Are there Tauberian/Abelian theorems which can apply? This comes from a particular problem when $a_n=n^2$ where I think I can show that
$$\lim_{x \to 1^-} \sqrt{1-x} \cdot f(x) =\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x^2} \,dx = \frac {\sqrt{\pi}}2,$$
by looking at it as an approximated Riemann sum. I am interested also at behaviors of other similar series like $f(x)= \sum_{p \; prime} \frac{x^p}p$ etc...

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1196721/proving-that-lim-x-to1-left-sqrta1-x-cdot-sum-n-0-inftyxna-ri

Comment: Thank you very much! I looked for similar posts but I couldn't find them. I would say that this extends easily to the case of polynomials. I found also the case $a_n=2^n$ which is interesting. How about $a_n=n!$ or $a_n=p$ with p prime?

Comment: I am not really familiar with theses sums... I hope the others will be. I am also interested by the case $2^n$. Where did you find it?

Comment: There are several answers already, here's one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296066/evaluate-lim-x-to1-left-sum-n-0-infty-leftx2n-right-log-2-f?rq=1

Comment: Using a very similar approach to the $n^2$ case, one should look at the convergence of the measures $\mu_k = \frac 1{A_k} \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \delta_{a_n/k}$, where $A_k= \{ n :  a_n \leq k\}$. Then if $\mu_k \rightharpoonup \mu$ for $k \to \infty$ morally one should have $\frac{f(1-1/k)}{A_k} \to \int_0^{\infty} e^{-x} \, d \mu$.